# How do I change the font color of an option only once it's been selected from a select drop down menu?

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to customize my select dropdown for my react app, what I want to achieve: Once an option has been selected from the drop down, I want the font color to turn black.

So, this is how the drop down appears before an option is selected (which is perfect, I want it like that):
[image]

and then this is what it looks like after an option is selected (which I don't want, I'm trying to make the text color black, as mentioned above):
[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems it's not possible. The selected option gets the color of the `select` tag.

Comment: yeah, I see. I want it to be clear that an option has been selected, so I want that color to change , there's definitely a way

Comment: Which react library does this dropdown component belong to?

Comment: I'm not using any libraries? I styled it with css @AhmetEmreKılınç

Comment: I'm new to react @AhmetEmreKılınç

Comment: So, did you create it using <select> and <option> tags?

Comment: yes! I did @AhmetEmreKılınç

Answer (score 0):

You can set `color` css attribute relative to the `value` of your dropdown like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [selectVal, setSelectVal] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={(e) => setSelectVal(e.target.value)}
        value={selectVal}
        style={{ color: selectVal ? "black" : "grey" }}
      >
        <option value="">state</option>
        <option value="new york">new york</option>
        <option value="washington">washington</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-mopsa-7mbdf?file=/src/App.js) for a live working example.